# Instances Scaled Weirdly

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am trying to add some "tank" like features to a geometry node based building. However, the tanks are being scaled weirdly despite trying to use a constant random value for X, Y, and Z inputs. To note, these tanks are instances *on instances* which **are** randomled scaled on X, Y, and Z seperately. Could this be why? Is there a way to fix this?

[image: Tanks weirdly scaled]

[image: Node Network]

I have tried using the random value itself, and the combine XYZ, or none, and they are always randomly scaled independently on X, Y, and Z.

Comment: Have you applied the scale to the base object that has the GN modifier?

Comment: maybe add a 'Realize Instances' to your points before second 'Instance on Points' node, as points can carry transformations and you got them from random scaled instances...

Comment: @Blunder I did not, however, that did not resolve the specific issue.

Comment: @alambre The did the trick! Thank you.

Comment: you're welcome... see you can get rid of that combine xyz node if 3 values are the same

Comment: @WASasquatch It would be great of you to write a short answer to this and mark it as "Accepted Answer" so that this question shows up as solved. Thank you!

Comment: Wow, it's been months. Don't even have this project any more to relate the fix to the issue without just saying what was said here in the comments, which isn't much an explanation to solution. This is a topic for the archives. Also considering I don't understand exactly why it fixes the issue, it would be negligent to try and explain.